# How do I send an incoming message to flex and also call a function? Connect 2 actions to 1 trigger

Tags: twilio, twilio-functions, twilio-studio, twilio-flex

Trying to connect 2 actions from 1 trigger in the message flow. I want to connect a function that will run after an incoming message arrives and also send this message to flex from their pre-made widget.

I am using twilio message flow widgets and functions.

Comment: Hey, what have you tried so far with this? Have you tried adding a function widget into the Studio flow before the message is forwarded to Flex?

Comment: I have, the problem is that I do not receive the context in it... do you know how could i setup the parameters or variables so that the function would work just like if it was called by an inbound sms for example?

Comment: My current setup is Trigger (Incoming Message) -> Function -> Send to Flex. The message gets to flex, but function never executes. When called, arent the context, event and callback passed from the incoming message to the function by default?

Comment: You would need to set the widget up to pass on the message parameters to the function, then they will be populated in the `event` object in the function.